# PHP: Handling (unexpected) arrays in user input

Tags: php, arrays, security

I recently discovered, that sending variables containing "unexpected" arrays - instead of strings - may lead to fatal errors or other undesired behaviour. Example:

We have the following array:

```
$list = array(
"a" => "first",
"b" => "second"
);
```

And a user sending `$_REQUEST["key"]`, which will be used to find a certain element in that list:

```
echo ($list[$_REQUEST["key"]] ?? null);
```

If `$_REQUEST["key"]` is of type `string`, `int`, `float`, `bool`or `null`, the script will either display the found entry or nothing (= null). Thats the desired behaviour.

If `$_REQUEST["key"]` is an `array`, the script will stop with a fatal error.

---

Now, the obvious solution would be to pave the entire code with thousands of type checks (`is_scalar()` or `!is_array()`). But I wondered if from a security perspective, the following alternative sounds reasonable:

Right at the start of every request, the following script will run:

```
$_COOKIE = array_map(function($e) { return (is_array($e) ? json_encode($e, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE) : $e); }, $_COOKIE);
$_REQUEST = array_map(function($e) { return (is_array($e) ? json_encode($e, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE) : $e); }, $_REQUEST);
$_POST = array_map(function($e) { return (is_array($e) ? json_encode($e, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE) : $e); }, $_POST);
$_GET = array_map(function($e) { return (is_array($e) ? json_encode($e, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE) : $e); }, $_GET);
```

Which essentially disables the function to send arrays to the server. If anywhere in the code arrays are actually expected, they would be manually decoded using `json_decode()`.

Is that a good idea?

Comment: HTTP transfers only strings. PHP automatically decodes the array notation... but the raw body is always string

Comment: I dont think you need to sanitize the input. Have you achieved to send an array via Html?

Comment: How is a "user" sending an array? Don't let them send an array...

Comment: @AbraCadaver You can send arrays by attaching a [] to the variable name. For example: page.php?key[]=first&key[]=second. It also works with HTML forms, where you add a [] to the name: <input name="key[]" value="first"> <input name="key[]" value="second">

Comment: Enforcing a ubiquitous scalar-only rule for all superglobals / user submissions is a myopic endeavor.  I would never do this.  you need to craft meaningful validations for EVERY individual access point of your project.  No short cuts.  Only write good, secure code.

Comment: @shuunenkinenbi I am aware of this, I guess why can a "user" send this?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Every user can. Simply edit the HTML code (form) or write something in the URL (GET-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You decode every input variable manually to avoid having to validate every input variable manually. To me, it's the same annoyance but more confusing, less performant and with new bugs (`json_encode()`, for instance, will break if input is not valid UTF-8).

In general terms, it pays off to be explicit about your application input. Ensuring that you work with a known set of variables which are in a known status really saves time and hassles.

```
$key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) && is_string($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : null;
$item = $list[$key] ?? null;
```

If `\TypeError` is your only concern, you can wrap everything in a try/catch block.

You can use functions to avoid code repetition:

```
function get(string $name, ?string $default = null): ?string
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name]) && is_string($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        return $_REQUEST[$name];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

You can build a validation framework or use a third-party one.

I'd do many things before messing all input only to prevent a specific corner case.

Comment: Here's another example why (for example) using try {} is not really an option. Lets say you define a function with type declarations like this: function doThings(?string $a) { }, whereas $a will be a variable provided by the user. If the user now manipulates the variable $a to be an array, that function call will throw a fatal error. Which leads to the same problem: You have to do thousands of manual is_scalar() / !is_array() checks before even sending the input to the function (rather than checking the input's validity in the function body itself or precautionary disabling all user-arrays).

Comment: I wouldn't do try/catch either, it was just an example to keep code verbosity to the minimum since it seemed important for you. If you have thousands of input variables, you need to do thousands of validations. That doesn't mean you need to write the same boilerplate code a thousand times. You have functions, you have loops, you have `array_map()`. Plus, if you have a thousand variables, using arrays may be a good solution after all, if only for your internal variables.

Comment: In my specific project, there are exactly 7 cases where the user input is supposed to be an array - compared to thousands of cases where the input is supposed to be string/int/float. Considering that large disparity it seems more reasonable to filter those 7 cases ("activating them manually with json_decode") instead of checking the thousands of other cases. You understand my train of thought?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't. But you don't need to convince me, code style issues are often subjective. If it works for you, do it that way. I just wanted to highlight some alternatives that sound more intuitive to me, that's all.